# Ubuntu 14.04 Unity or Gnome?

Tags: unity, upgrade

There is no problem at this time with any software, as I am simply trying to get ready for 14.04.
Do I need to uninstall the gnome from 13.10 or will everything upgrade properly. I cannot find any information on the internet about 14.04
Again, THERE IS NO BUG.

Comment: It isn't that this is a bug, it's that 14.04 is a development version.  See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseSchedule . Generally, things will upgrade properly, but the best results are usually achieved with a clean install.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have installed GNOME (3.8) from the standard Ubuntu 13.10 repositories, there is no need to uninstall before upgrading.

If you have [installed the more recent version](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/12/upgrade-gnome-3-10-ubuntu-13-10) of GNOME 3.10 through the GNOME PPA, you should remove it first with the `ppa-purge` utility following the instructions in the linked article. This will downgrade the GNOME packages to the versions in the official Ubuntu repository so that the distribution upgrade can proceed smoothly.